# Playing a video using the IFrame API on a ARMv7-based Android device, causes high quality videos to lag and show green artifacts on the video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api, armv7

The code below shows a simple Android app that utilizes the Youtube IFrame API to play a specific video link.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
            myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",   "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                                                "<html>\n" +
                                                "<body>\n" +
                                                "\n" +
                                                "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n"
                                                "\n" +
                                                "<p>My first paragraph.</p›\n" +
                                                "<iframe id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"720\" height=\"405\"\n" +
                                                "src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/?playlist=w0eVN8mqtiw\"\n" +
                                                "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen›\n" +
                                                "</body>\n" +
                                                "</html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "")
        }
    }
```

This code plays well on ARMv8-based Android devices.

However, on 2 ARMv7-based Android devices I tried, it causes the relatively high-quality video https://www.youtube.com/embed/?playlist=w0eVN8mqtiw to lag and show green artifacts after a couple of seconds.

1. **This happens ONLY if the quality of playback is set to Auto** (which is the default option for every YouTube link we play using the IFrame player).
2. **Once I set the quality of playback (manually in the IFrame player playback settings), to any specific supported resolution, the lagging and green artifact disappears.** This means this issue is somehow related to the Auto playback quality adaptations of the IFrame player in high-quality (1080p+) Youtube videos

That being said any video below 1080p, works fine (without lags or green artifacts).
That is not being caused due to network issues since all devices I tested used the same network.

Moreover, the same video link plays well on the device's Youtube app as well as in IFrame player running directly on a Chrome web page (used https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo to play the same link).

[image]

Any idea what could be the issue or how it can be avoided?